# STM32 SD FATFS mount error (FR_NOT_READY)

Tags: c, stm32, sd-card, fatfs, stm32cubemx

I'm actually trying to write on a µSD card with a STM32L486QGI6.
The function `f_mount()` returns `FR_NOT_READY` whether the µSD is placed or not...

I already checked dozens of tutorials and examples for CubeMX generation (Checked the pins, the SD_Detect in pull-down, Pull-Ups for the other pins except CK, global interrupts, Clock of 40MHz divided by 4, etc...)

There is the code I'm using :

```
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"
#include "fatfs.h"
#include <string.h>

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */
FRESULT testing;
FRESULT res;                                 
/* USER CODE END PV */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */
    uint32_t byteswritten, bytesread;                /* File write/read counts */
    uint8_t wtext[] = "STM32 FATFS works great!";    /* File write buffer */
    uint8_t rtext[_MAX_SS];                          /* File read buffer */
  /* USER CODE END 1 */
  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/
  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */
  /* USER CODE END Init */
  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */
  /* USER CODE END SysInit */
  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_DMA_Init();
  MX_SDMMC1_SD_Init();
  MX_FATFS_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */ 
    res = f_mount(&SDFatFS, (const TCHAR *)SDPath, 1);
    const TCHAR tt[]="STM32.txt";
    testing = f_open(&SDFile, tt, FA_CREATE_ALWAYS | FA_WRITE);
    res = f_write(&SDFile, wtext, strlen((char *)wtext), (void *)&byteswritten);
    f_close(&SDFile);
  /* USER CODE END 2 */
  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {    
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */
    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

/**
  * @brief SDMMC1 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_SDMMC1_SD_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SDMMC1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END SDMMC1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SDMMC1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END SDMMC1_Init 1 */
  hsd1.Instance = SDMMC1;
  hsd1.Init.ClockEdge = SDMMC_CLOCK_EDGE_RISING;
  hsd1.Init.ClockBypass = SDMMC_CLOCK_BYPASS_DISABLE;
  hsd1.Init.ClockPowerSave = SDMMC_CLOCK_POWER_SAVE_DISABLE;
  hsd1.Init.BusWide = SDMMC_BUS_WIDE_4B;
  hsd1.Init.HardwareFlowControl = SDMMC_HARDWARE_FLOW_CONTROL_ENABLE;
  hsd1.Init.ClockDiv = 4;
  /* USER CODE BEGIN SDMMC1_Init 2 */
  /* USER CODE END SDMMC1_Init 2 */
}

/**
  * Enable DMA controller clock
  */
static void MX_DMA_Init(void)
{

  /* DMA controller clock enable */
  __HAL_RCC_DMA2_CLK_ENABLE();

  /* DMA interrupt init */
  /* DMA2_Channel4_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA2_Channel4_IRQn, 2, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA2_Channel4_IRQn);
  /* DMA2_Channel5_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA2_Channel5_IRQn, 2, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA2_Channel5_IRQn);

}

/**
  * @brief GPIO Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOE_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOD_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOG_CLK_ENABLE();
  HAL_PWREx_EnableVddIO2();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOE, GPIO_PIN_1|GPIO_PIN_0, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOE, GPIO_PIN_2, GPIO_PIN_SET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_12, GPIO_PIN_SET);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : PE1 PE2 PE0 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_1|GPIO_PIN_2|GPIO_PIN_0;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOE, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : SD_DETECT_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = SD_DETECT_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLDOWN;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(SD_DETECT_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : PB12 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_12;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

}
```

And the CubeMX configurations :

- [image]
- [image]
- [image]
- [image]
- [image]
- [image]
- **FATFS configuration :**

[image]

- [image]
- [image]
- [image]

Comment: Do not check tutorials - **DEBUG** your program to see what has failed#

Answer (score 0):

change hardware flow control to "disabled"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31361138)